# php simple associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I've done this a million times but for some reason I can't get this to work today...

I have this associative array

```
 Array
 (
     [0] => stdClass Object
         (
             [registrantKey] => 106569618
             [firstName] => xxx
             [lastName] => yyy
             [email] => x@x.x

         )

     [1] => stdClass Object
         (
             [registrantKey] => 106975808
             [firstName] => qqq
             [lastName] => ppp
             [email] => aaa@aaa.com

         )
 ...
 ...
```

I just want to get the first name of each one of them, im using a foreach loop but doesn't really let me get what I want.

Any ideas?

```
 foreach($array as $key=>$value){
      echo $value['firstName'];
 }
```

Comment: Use `$value->firstName`, as it's an object

Answer (score 0):

For this case, your array element isn't an array but an object.

As such, it should be:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    echo $value->firstName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
  echo $value->firstName;
}
```

You have `stdClass Objects` as array elements and not associative arrays so you need the option notation: `$value->firstName`

You could also convert the `stdClass Object` to array by type casting:

```
foreach($array as $key=> (array) $value){
  echo $value['firstName'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$value->firstName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
foreach($array as $key=> (array) $value){
     echo $value['firstName'];
}
```

This will typecast your object to an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

 $array = (array)$array; 
 $firstNames = array();
 foreach($array as $a)
 {
     $firstNames[] = $a['firstName'];
 }
 print_r($firstNames);

?>
```